# Убрать пробел в пути

Tags: python, path

Получаю расположение файла
`system = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))`

`print(format(system),"\\person\\age1\\{0}".format(name1))`

Получаю `C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\tests \person\age1\Gulag` Как убрать пробел?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо

```
print(format(system),"\\person\\age1\\{0}".format(name1))
```

(два параметра с запятой между ними)

используйте

```
print(format(system) + "\\person\\age1\\{0}".format(name1))
```

(один параметр - вместо `,` знак `+` для соединения 2 строк в 1)

т.к. `print()` вставит пробел между параметрами.